# Views and subviews

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to put a view with subviews. The view has an image and a text, which are subviews, but when i run the app, it doesn't show the complete text. Here is the code…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    let ballonview = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let turn = 1
    
    
    ballonview.frame = CGRectZero
    
    label.frame = CGRectZero
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)
    
    let message = UIView()
    message.frame = CGRectMake(-160, 48, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
    message.addSubview(ballonview)
    message.addSubview(label)
    
    
    let text: NSString = "hola como estas"
    
    let size:CGSize = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesDeviceMetrics, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)], context: nil).size
    
    
    var ballon:UIImage = UIImage()
    

    ballonview.frame = CGRectMake(320.0 - (size.width + 28.0), 2.0, size.width + 28.0, size.height + 15.0)
    ballon = UIImage(named:"green.png")!.stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth(24, topCapHeight: 15)
    label.frame = CGRectMake(307.0 - (size.width + 5.0), 8.0, size.width + 5.0, size.height)
    
    ballonview.image = ballon;
    label.text = text as String
    view.addSubview(message)

}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using different font sizes when measuring the `size` and rendering.

The `font` of `label` is 20pt system font, and the font you use for measuring `size` is 14pt system font. So the `size` will be smaller than you expected.

Also, the drawing options should be changed to `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` in order to get the correct size if you have characters with *long legs* (like `g`, `j`, `y`).

Reference: [official NSString document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:).

I'd suggest you change the way you measure the `size`:

```
let size: CGSize = text.boundingRectWithSize(
    CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0),
    options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
    attributes: [
        NSFontAttributeName: label.font
    ],
    context: nil
).size
```

So it will match the font you use for rendering the `label`.

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: When i put some letters, like "j" or "g" , the letters are cute... what can i do???

Comment: does `size.height = ceil(size.height)` help?

Comment: sorry, should be `size.height = CGFloat(ceil(Float(size.height)))`